# Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0), Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to delete and add list of records to a database, I get the errors shown here if multiple users update at the same time.

> System.Data.Entity.Core.OptimisticConcurrencyException
>
> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

```
using (DBEntities dbcontext = new DBEntities())
{
   System.Data.Entity.DbContextTransaction DbTransaction = dbcontext.Database.BeginTransaction();

   try
   {
      // delete the old value
      List<User> ListTemp1 = (from a in dbcontext.Users.AsEnumerable() select a ).ToList();

      if (ListTemp1 != null && ListTemp1.Count > 0)
      {
          dbcontext.Users.RemoveRange(ListTemp1);
          dbcontext.SaveChanges();
      }

      List<User> ListTemp2 = (from a in dbcontext.TempUsers.AsEnumerable() select a).ToList();

      if (ListTemp2 != null && ListTemp2.Count > 0)
      { 
          dbcontext.Users.AddRange(ListTemp2);
          dbcontext.SaveChanges();
      }

      DbTransaction.Commit();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      DbTransaction.Rollback();
      throw ex;
   }
   finally
   {
      DbTransaction.Dispose();
   }
}
```

How can I fix it, with current code it doesn't work? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, the same context instance can be used for updates, deletes, and inserts.  In fact, you can do all 3 operations at once, with only a single call to `SaveChanges`.  You don't need to call it individually after every operation.

Comment: However you are trying to add the same entity to 2 places, why not just have a flag called `bool TempUser`?

Comment: So you have a `DbContext` with a `DbSet<User> Users` and a `DbSet<User> TempUsers`? Entity Framework does not allow two tables with equal type

Comment: This is just an example of my error.